# PHP application configuration

Tags: php, security

I've started looking at Heroku for application hosting and deployment and it appears that my configuration constants need to be stored in environment variables. I can do this in Heroku, but my application might also be deployed to shared servers and it may not be secure according to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20282/is-passing-sensitive-data-through-the-process-environment-secure/).

Basically I want the information to be read from a configuration file if it is present, otherwise try to read from the environment variables (in the case of Heroku).

1. Is this the best way of doing it?
2. Are there security implications?

### settings.php

```
<?php

define('DB_URL', 'mysql://root:password@localhost:3306/database');
define('APP_URL', '[::1]');
define('APP_URL_PATH', '/path/to/application');
define('FOO', 'more things');
```

### config.php

```
<?php

if (!is_file('settings.php')) {
    require 'settings.php';
    return;
}

define('DB_URL', getenv('DB_URL'));
define('APP_URL', getenv('APP_URL'));
define('APP_URL_PATH', getenv('APP_URL_PATH'));
define('FOO', getenv('FOO'));
```

### index.php (and other application files)

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim\App();

// code

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if `settings.php` is in the same directory tree where you have other scripts like `index.php` served by the web server.
I don't know if this is possible on Heroku,
but I recommend to move files that should never be served by the web server outside of the document root.

One time, I had a web server malfunction: the well-tuned configuration file got replaced with something primitive, and php disabled, where visiting settings.php in a browser would simply display the contents of the file without running through the PHP interpreter. Sure, this seems unlikely to happen, but by moving sensitive files outside the document root, you can effectively safeguard against such or similar misconfiguration issues. I also find it good organization to separate public files from internal details. So my PHP projects all have a `public/` directory inside, containing practically views only, the model is elsewhere, cleanly separated.

About this:

> ```
> define('DB_URL', 'mysql://root:password@localhost:3306/database');
> ```

Even if it's a dedicated and isolated database for your project only,
I don't see why would you ever use the `root` account.
Create a dedicated user with carefully selected grants instead.

Needless to say, `settings.php` should have restrictive permissions in the filesystem.

Comment: The `root` user is only used in the local development environment. There is a proper user configured with the appropriate permissions on the actual deployment environments. And I believe `settings.php` has permissions of 744.

Comment: `settings.php` doesn't need to be executable. And it may depend on your webserver setup, but most probably it shouldn't need to be readable by group and other. So 600 permission should be enough. It's a security sensitive file, so it's good to tune the permissions to the minimum necessary.

Comment: 9 months later and my proposal to move to envvars finally got accepted… [this library](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) really helps for dev.

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps use a JSON string for configuration purposes.

The JSON might look like this:

```
{
    "DB_URL":"mysql://root:password@localhost:3306/database",
    "APP_URL", "[::1]",
    ...
}
```

And reading it into constants might look like this:

```
$config_file = '/path/to/config.json';
if(is_file($config_file) && is_readable($config_file) {
    // get file system config   
    $configs = json_decode(file_get_contents($config_file), true);
} else if(!empty(getenv('heroku_config')) {
    // use Heroku config value
    $configs = json_decode(getenv('heroku_config'), true);
} else {
    throw new Exception('No config found!');
}

// load configs into constants
foreach($configs as $key => $value) {
    define($key, $value);
}
```

This leave a very flexible configuration model where you can easily change configs, without needing to change your code at all.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! `.json` files are often directly readable on webservers, so that you would get the actual content of it. The positive thing about a .php config file is that there's no way for a visitor to see the actual content of that php file. I would personally not recommend a JSON configuration for PHP.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg You obviously would not put it in a web directory, nor would you want to even for a PHP file.

Comment: Sure, that would help. But what is really the advantage of modifying a JSON file instead of a PHP file?

Comment: What is easier about changing a JSON file compared to a `settings.php` file with `define` statements as in the question?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg This would allow you to change your configuration, without having to change your code.

Comment: @janos This would allow you to change your configuration, without having to change your code.

Comment: If it was a compiled language, then you would have a point, as changes to the source file with constants would require a rebuild + redeploy. Or if you wanted to consume the same config file by +1 application in a different language, then it *could* be a good idea to choose JSON as the common configuration format. But none of this is the case. As it stands, there's nothing in the question to call for this. Changing a simple `settings.php` file is as effortless as changing `settings.json`, even to non-programmers, and adding JSON seems a bit pointless overhead.

Comment: @janos Yes, but say that you didn't want your database passwords and such to be part of your revision controlled code base, as would be desirable from an application security standpoint.  Yuo best solution is to separate these sorts of configuration management concerns from the application codebase.

Comment: Certainly you don't want to include your production config in the VCS of the code base, but that's the same whether you have them in `settings.php` or `settings.json`.